# sql server 2008 r2 improve performance

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I want to improve the performance of my SQL select query. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table `Orders` which has around 1.5 lacs of rows.

I have written a simple

```
select * from Orders
```

query which is taking around 8 seconds. Due to this the UI component is getting displayed in around 10-11 seconds.

Can anybody tell what could be issue? Is it due to no index is created on the table? If yes how we can improve the performance?

after edit---

I have posted query the above..which is a simple "select * from Orders".Orders is the table name.in which orderId is the primary key.i guess the DB will create a index for the primary key.I have also mentioned that there are not indexes created on any column in the table.the table as total 0.15 million records.i am running the query in the sql server management studio.even to my surprise the query is taking 8 seconds to show the results.

Thanks,
Hanmayya

Comment: Posting the query, execution plan, table structure, indexes, etc would be really helpful. I don't think anyone on here is psychic and can read your query without seeing it.

Comment: Using SQL Server Management Studio, run the query and select "Include Action Execution Plan" from the toolbar.  The execution plan will indicate in detail what the SQL server is doing to fulfill the query and specifically where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Are you trying to display 150,000 records onto your screen?

Comment: I have posted query the above..which is a simple select * from Orders.Orders is the table name.in which orderId is the primary key.i guess the DB will create a index for the primary key.I have also mentioned that there are not indexes created on any column in the table.the table as total 0.15 million records.i am running the query in the sql server management studio.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with what unit "lacs" is, but you could look at the following to try to improve performance.

1. Try selecting only the fields that you need.
2. Remove any kind of formatting from the control.  A friend of mine was encountering some issue with a Telerik grid when he was trying some non-standard configuration.
3. See if there is a problem with the server (is cpu/ram maxing out?)
4. Is there a problem with the network?
5. Do other servers have the same issue? You could compare configurations to see what the difference is.
6. Is the table fragmented? Not sure how much this would affect select performance though.

If you are not using any joins I do not think that putting an index would improve anything.

Comment: let me add some more data.the table has 22 column, out of which 8 columns have FK relation with other table, but my question is though the table has just 0.15 million records, a simple select * from <orders> table is taking around 8 seconds to execute the query.what could be the reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Just to update on the answer, I have implemented row index to fetch the data based on no of records to be displayed on page and the start index.